# Convert PDF from RGB to CMYK with Ghostscript

Tags: pdf, docker, ghostscript, cmyk

I'm using the following command to convert the color profile of a PDF from RGB to CMYK:

```
gs -dSAFER \
-dBATCH \
-dNOPAUSE \
-dNOCACHE \
-dPDFX \
-sDEVICE=pdfwrite 
-sColorConversionStrategy=CMYK 
-sOutputFile=cmyk.pdf rgb.pdf
```

The PDF of the test is for demo purposes to check the support of what I need.

[image: Image of PDF for reference]

On my local machine the script produces this as result:

[image].

But when I try to convert this inside a Docker container the same script produces this:

[image: this]

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get install -y ghostscript`
```

Comment: Have you checked the two versions of Ghostscript ? Are they the same ? Remember to check the actual executables you are using. Please state which version you are using. Why are you setting -dPDFX ? Likewise, why -dNOCACHE ? Have you checked the actual content of each PDF file ? I'd also suggest you post the original and each output file somewhere so they can be inspected.

Comment: They aren't the same, the Docker are in 9.18 and the systems I've tested(Ubuntu 17.10 and macOS High Sierra) in the 9.21. All worked as expected when the container upgraded his version, thanks. I totally forgot to check the versions. The -dPDFX it's to be as close as possible of a PDF exported by the Illustrator and the -dNOCACHE is from the original command that I've found to do the conversion.

Comment: I'm afraid the command line you are using isn't sufficient to create a valid PDF/X-3 file (the pdfwrite device currently only supports the X-3 flavour). There's more information on creating an X-3 file here https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.22/VectorDevices.htm#PDFX If you don't want to do that, then I'd recommend dropping the -dPDFX as an incomplete setup could lead to problems and the creation of invalid files. I wouldn't use -dNOCACHE at all, that will prevent font embedding, all the text will be converted to vector operations or images. That's really not a good thing at all.